# Show that $\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac\epsilon{10}\right\}$ implies $\lim_{x\to 1}3x=3$ in the context of the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

Suppose that $\epsilon>0$ and let $\delta=\min\left\{1, \dfrac{\epsilon}{10}\right\}$.
Show that $\lim_{x\to 1}3x=3$.

Can someone please help me, I have no idea what to do. I know to start like this:

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given and $\delta=\min\left\{1, \dfrac{\epsilon}{10}\right\}$. If  $0<|x-1|<\delta$ then:

$$|3x-3|=3|x-1|<3\delta<3\dfrac{\epsilon}{10}.$$

But how do I get to $=\epsilon$?

Comment: $3\epsilon/10<\epsilon$ Very confusing in any case.

Comment: What's this "$\min\{1,\epsilon/10\}$" trend? Cf. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1743385/epsilon-delta-proof and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1743330/verification-epsilon-delta.

Answer (score 1):

You have showed correctly that $$\vert 3x-3\vert<\frac 3{10}\epsilon.$$
But you also know that $\frac3{10}\epsilon<\epsilon$, always. So you may simply say $$\vert 3x-3\vert<\frac3{10}\epsilon<\epsilon$$ and you're done.

---

N.B. I noticed you wrote you want to get $=\epsilon$ somewhere. This is not what you want. Just take another (very scrutinous) look at the definition of limit once more.